# Search engine mechanism with multiple arguments

Tags: php, mysql, search, codeigniter, search-engine

I am creating a new website using **CodeIgniter/PHP/MySQL**.

I have the mechanism to pass some items in my database, which has each **3 fields and a description**.

Now I want to create a search mechanism for those, with the following features:

- Search for a keyword **in both 3 fields and description**.
- The user can select **multiple values for the 3 fields**.
- **Combine the above two**, if user both selects multiple values and a keyword

I already can parse the data and create something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`My_Table`) 
    WHERE 
        `description` COLLATE utf8_general_ci 
            REGEXP '\[\[:<:\]\]asdasdasd\[\[:>:\]\]' 
        AND `value1` LIKE '%blabla%' 
        OR `value1` LIKE 'lala'
```

but it's far from what I want to create!

I am not expert in SQL, so I am having a hard time to find a way to do this.

If anyone knows/wants, please please help me!!
Thanks in advance!

Note: Code samples/Examples will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give examples using a proper schema? I'm not sure what 'multiple values for 3 fields' means? I'm assuming field1 = value1, field2 = value2, field3 = value3 approach? Or selecting which field/value combination to search through?

Comment: I mean that field1 = value1 OR value2 OR value3 and the field2 = value4 OR value5 OR value6, but both should be field1 and field2 should be compined for the results, like field1 AND field2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full text search for this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

This will help you alot.

Note: Table should use MyISAM Storage engine and column should be full text indexed.